# Geocoder gem in rails returning : over query limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoder

I have a model Events with `geocoded_by :address` and `after_validation :geocode`, I also have a google api key in my `geocoder.rb (initializer)`. The key is enabled for GeocodingAPi. When I run .geocode in console I have a limit error message.

```
2.5.3 :024 > Geocoder.coordinates("25 Main St, Cooperstown, NY")
Google API error: over query limit.
```

or

```
2.5.3 :030 > a.full_address
 => "80,  Rue des Capucins, Paris" 
2.5.3 :031 > a.geocode
Google API error: over query limit.
 => nil 
2.5.3 :032 >
```

I have not used that API at all today, so I am sure this cannot be a limit issue. I am testing on localhost, so cannot be a shared server limit issue either. 
Anybody know what should be done/checked in such case ?

```
Geocoder.configure(
   lookup: :google,            
   ip_lookup: :ipinfo_io,      
   use_https: true,           
   api_key: nil,               
   cache: Redis.new,                 
  api_key: 'AIzaSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Geolocation API is not free, it has limit. check the website [gecoding usage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing#standard-usage-limits)

Comment: In case someone else look for it for hours, this is the link to go quick:
https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable?redirect=https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing?dialogOnLoad%3Dbilling-enabled&_ga=2.45638692.1407938638.1547003953-2127324926.1547003953